# What is the meaning and cause of 999 HTTP error code received from Tomcat

Tags: java, html, rest, web-services, tomcat7

What is the meaning and cause of 999 HTTP error code received from Tomcat.

Logs in access.log:
[12/Mar/2018:10:27:30 +0100]  172.19.160.65 -  172.19.160.71 POST 8081  999

Comment: That's not an HTTP error code, it should be how many bytes were sent to your client and might not be relevant to your problem(s)

Comment: 999 code is nonstandard, ask whoever is operating the tomcat server.

Comment: The content of the access.log file depends on how your Tomcat's access log valve is configured (specifically the "pattern").  What you have there doesn't look like the default pattern, so that `999` could be a few things.  But it is unlikely that it is the status code.